# Can't Install Lightworks in KDE

Tags: kde, deb

Everytime i try to install lightworks i get.

Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libtiff5

Please help!

Comment: libtiff5 is a tagged information file format library.  Try installing the library like this.   `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev`  Then re-try your lighworks install.

Comment: I tryed it but i get reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libtiff5-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libtiff5-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: See the answer below.  This should work, if so, please accept his answer.  Also, have you installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`?

Comment: How are you trying to install Lightworks?

Answer (score 0):

libtiff5 is not in the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 12.04. The Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library in Ubuntu 12.04 is an older version called libtiff4. To install libtiff4 in Ubuntu 12.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff4
```